# Entity Framework code first generating compound primary key not working

Tags: entity-framework-5

As per all the examples I see, this code should generate a compound primary key, but for some reason it isn't in my case.

```cs
  public abstract class MyBase
  {
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
  }

  public abstract class MyClass : MyBase
  {
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public AnotherClass AnotherClass { get; set; }
  }

  public abstract class AnotherClass : MyBase
  {
  }
```

I am expecting the `MyClass` table to have a compound foreign key consisting of `Id` and `AnotherClass_Id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing `Add-Migration -Force` and that redid the scaffolding of my migration, then I did `Update-Database`.

But I have found that after doing `Add-Migration -Force` it's useful to look at the generated migration file and see if the effect is what I intended before updating the database.